# Function JQuery doesn't works in Firefox

Tags: jquery

i'm using this function to change the color of my input text when the select change, the function take the color of the option selected, and put on the input text. This function works well on Chrome and Opera, but on Firefox change the color only for white. Help?

**Select:**

```
*<select class="target" id='cor' name='cor'  >
<option style="color:black" <?php if ($inicializaCor == 1 ) echo    'selected'; ?> value='preto'  >Preto</option>
<option style="color:blue" <?php if ($inicializaCor == 2 ) echo 'selected'; ?> value='azul'  >Azul</option>  
<option style="color:red" <?php if ($inicializaCor == 3 ) echo 'selected'; ?> value='vermelho'  >Vermelho</option>  
</select>*
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#cor" ).change();
});
$( "#cor" ).change(function() {
  var teste = $('#cor').find('option:selected').css("color");
  $( '#usuario' ).css("color",teste);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put all your code inside DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cor").change(function() {
        var teste = $('#cor').find('option:selected').css("color");
        $( '#usuario' ).css("color",teste);
    }).change(); // here you can trigger .change() instead of separate handler
});
```

---

In order to get the color value as name from your HTML, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cor").change(function() {
        var teste = $('#cor').find('option:selected')[0].style.color;
        console.log(teste);
        $( '#usuario' ).css("color",teste);
    }).change(); // here you can trigger .change() instead of separate handler
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2USPT/1/)**

Comment: I put all code inside DOM ready, but don't work in firefox... I put an alert to see the color that is captured, on Firefox just returns RGB(255,255,255). Have any other way to capture the color?

Comment: What's your expected result? It works fine here on Firefox for me: http://jsfiddle.net/2USPT/

Comment: My expected result is the color of the selected option, the first selected is black, the second is blue, and the last is red. I need that return to put in the color of input text. On Chrome and Opera, works well, but don't work on Firefox. If you want, can see on that link: http://rafadeolindo.url.ph/entrar.php

Comment: Thanks man, now worked on Firefox! Sorry for my inexperience and my bad/poor english. Really thanks!